# Put Route returns CSRF token mismatch Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postman, crud, endpoint

I am trying to configure a crud api for a blog and right now i made the PostController like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Post;
use App\Http\Requests\StorePostRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return response()->json([
            'posts' => $posts
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(StorePostRequest $request)
    {
        $post = Post::create($request->all());

        return response()->json([
            'message' => "Post Created successfully!",
            'post' => $post
        ], 200);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(Post $post)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     */
    public function edit(Post $post)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(StorePostRequest $request, Post $post)
    {
        $post->update($request->all());

        return response()->json([
            'message' => "Post Updated successfully!",
            'post' => $post
        ], 200);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy(Post $post)
    {
        $post->delete();

        return response()->json([
            'status' => true,
            'message' => "Post Deleted successfully!",
        ], 200);
    }
}
```

and web.php is this one:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('posts', PostController::class);
```

and when i try to use postman
http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/ works and shows me all the data but nothing else
And yes i switched the GET with POST and even tried with PUT
and i get the following:

```
 "message": "CSRF token mismatch.",
```

I do not have any front-end in this project to put that csrf field there, how should i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Api routes should be registered in the `routes/api.php` file, not in the `web.php` file. The middleware stack that is applied to the routes in these files is different.

One of the middlewares that is applied to routes in the `web.php` file is `VerifyCsrfToken`, but your requests will never have a csrf-token. Moving your api routes from `web.php` to `api.php` will resolve the csrf-token issues.

From the `RouteServiceProvider`:

```php
$this->routes(function () {
    Route::middleware('api') // api is a middleware group
        ->prefix('api')
        ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

    Route::middleware('web') // web is a middleware group
        ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
});
```

The middleware groups correspond with these middleware stacks:

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class, // causes the issue
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
 
    'api' => [ // does not have the csrf middleware
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

Comment: since i cannot figure out how to test an api in postman i tried commenting the verifycsrftoken and still used the web routes and here it is the next error:
"message": "No query results for model [App\\Models\\Post] store",

Comment: 1. Is there a model in the database? 2. What URL are you using when sending the request?

Comment: 2) http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/store?title=ceva&content=ceva&user_id=3
1)no

Comment: You are sending a `GET` request with `GET` parameters. It is sending your request to the `index` route (and method). You need to send a `POST` request and send the data as a `json` body.

This also explains the error that no models are found.

Comment: ok i found out how to test the api routes and now i try this url:
``` http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/store?title=ceva&content=ceva&user_id=3 ```
and it shows not found

Comment: Since the routes are still in `web.php` the `/api/` prefix will not be applied. The url is still just `/posts` and not `/api/posts`.  You are still sending a GET request with parameters. [this tutorial](https://apidog.com/articles/how-to-send-json-post-reques-with-postman/) shows how to send a post request with json body.

Comment: you said i put on the wrong prefix with GET but when i use POST postman returns:
```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The POST method is not supported for route api/posts/store. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE. in file 
```
And it works only with PUT but with PUT it says "Not Found"

Comment: The url is not `posts/store` but just `/posts`. The url is generated like that because you are using a resource controller. This is in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller).

Comment: Got it it was because of that resource you were right, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have a front-end for this project, you need to set the csrf token on the device sending the request. Setting 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' headers should solve your problem. More information in here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header